# connecting client to several servers in the same time, and execute a code in all the servers by the connection

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I was wondering how to:

- Connect client to several servers in the same time
- Execute a script code of a certain programming language to a different programming language server, Example:

  We create a connection between 3 servers, two have the same programming language(C++) and one has a different one (PHP), then, when a c++ server does a something, it informs the other c++ server and the php server, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
int startOthers (char* host, unsigned int port, char* msg) {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (sockfd > 0) {
        memset ((void *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof (serv_addr));

        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (host);
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons (port);

        if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr)) == 0) {
            write(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
            close (sockfd);

            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int startServer(unsigned int port) {
    int n, sockfd, cl_sockfd;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256 + 1];
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd > 0) {
        memset((void *) &server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));

        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

        if (bind(sockfd, (sockaddr *) & server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == 0) {
            listen(sockfd, 5);
            clilen = sizeof(client_addr);
            cl_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &clilen);

            if (cl_sockfd > 0) {
                while ( (n = read(cl_sockfd, buffer, 256)) <= 0); /* a client communicated with me */

                /* Do something */

                /* Inform others */
                startOthers(/* other C++ host */, /* port */, buffer);
                startOthers(/* php host */, /* port */, buffer);

                close(cl_sockfd);
                close(sockfd);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        close(sockfd);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The startOthers function can be used in conjunction with pthreads to initiate multiple connections at the same time. It can connect to socket created using php as well.

It is important that all the servers follow a protocol for communication despite their implementation details.